# Could not load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 3.1.0.0 but I am making reference to 3.1.5.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

This is usually a pretty simple issue as the error is quite clear but for some reason not in my case.

Essentially we have a few split up projects and the nuget packages gets installed in the shared project with the rest of the websites making reference to them. Instead we reference them in the web.config file and on build they get put in the bin folder.

In my current issue we are referencing Abstractions 3.1.5.0 yet now its complaining that it wants 3.1.0.0

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.5.0" newVersion="3.1.5.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I have tried the following.

1. Actually installing the nuget package (v3.1.5) but get the same error
2. Added the following in the project file
        `<PropertyGroup> <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects> <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType> </PropertyGroup>`

Funny thing is that when I installed v3.1.0 I got an error saying that its looking for 3.1.5.
This is also working fine for every other project except this one

Comment: Is it possible that another package you've added is looking at that version?

Comment: I was also thinking that but then I would have had this issue in other projects as well as they have all similar references.

Comment: Have you tried to remove Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions from all project files?

Comment: It definitely is needed for one of the other dll's we use for configuration

Comment: @Sl1ver: It was a shot in the dark :-) I cleaned up a couple of projects here after upgrading to Core 3.1, and a lot of dependencies were redundant, among them Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions

Answer (score 0):

A malformed web.config caused the issue. This might have happened during a merge.

I had sections that had 2 references within a dependentAssembly tag, once I separated them, deleted bin and obj folders I got it working again.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.5.1.0" newVersion="6.5.1.0"/>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.14.0.17971" newVersion="2.14.0.17971"/>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```